# Django import export imports not showing

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

[image]

I applied the code as the documentation suggested. But my csv data is now being shown

[image]

Comment: Your Field `attribute` property should match an attribute on the model.  Check out [this example](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/tests/core/tests/test_resources.py#L252).  If your csv names match your attribute names, you shouldn't need to declare Fields.  If it's still not working, please post back with more information (guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Hey Thanks I figured it out after posting. Anyways is there a way to change the coloumn name  of the export file? Like in the imported csv the coloumn name is surname but in the export i want it to be lastname. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I suggest look at overriding [`before_export()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.before_export)

Comment: should is use tablib in this function?

Comment: Please post a new question and I'll respond accordingly